# Is it safe to run servers in a room that contains a boiler? [fire safety]

Tags: electrical, fire

My landlord says I can use the garage in our house for an office.

The garage contains a gas combi boiler.

Is it safe to setup servers in this garage?

If not, is there any way to make it safe?

I'm worried about the fire safety aspect of it, I don't want to blow up my flatmates.

Comment: Where on the planet are you btw?

Comment: North East of England.

Answer (score 3):

The regulations say for domestic premises you must maintain 150mm separation between any low pressure gas pipework and any electrical equipment. The specific room location is irrelevant.

So it would seem for your scenario you will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be any danger problems running servers.  But depending upon the number and size of servers you might have a heat problem. I believe Google runs their server farms in the 80s F to save on AC costs. The combi boiler had better not be leaking any gas!!!!!!  Even if so, a server wouldn't ignite it, other sources would.  And you could def. smell it if any gas were leaking.

Other than any defects, I think you'll be fine if you can address the potential heat problem.